# Showing 'error converting data type nvarchar to bigint. in sql server'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

By using `nvarchar(Max)` and join the query and execute by EXEC `sp_executesql` during this process it showing the above error error converting data type nvarchar to bigint. in sql server, with out using the joining and `sp_executesql` it will workd perfect. how can i solve the this error in sql.

```
DECLARE 
        @mainSqlQuery nvarchar(max),
        @GroupBySection nvarchar(max)

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @mainSqlQuery = N'--
    SELECT 
    BRCH.BranchName         [BranchName],
    ASI.SubInventoryName    [SubInventory],
    APRO.ProductName        [Product],
    ASICT.TransactDateTime  [DateTime],
    ASICT.ProductStock      [Stock],
    ASICT.ProductStockInLocalCrrncy [Local Stock] INTO #MyTempTable
    FROM ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers ASICT
    INNER JOIN 
        ALX_Branches BRCH      ON BRCH.BranchID= ASICT.BranchID
    INNER JOIN 
        ALX_SubInventories ASI ON ASI.SubInventoryID=ASICT.SubInventoryID
    INNER JOIN 
        ALX_Products APRO      ON APRO.ProductID= ASICT.ProductID
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT
            BranchID,
            SubInventoryID,
            ProductID,
            MAX(TransactDateTime) AS MaxDate
        FROM ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers'         

    Select @GroupBySection = N'--   GROUP BY BranchID,
                 SubInventoryID,
                 ProductID) SubASICT
              ON ASICT.BranchID = SubASICT.BranchID
             AND ASICT.SubInventoryID = SubASICT.SubInventoryID
             AND ASICT.ProductID = SubASICT.ProductID
             AND ASICT.TransactDateTime = SubASICT.MaxDate'

    Declare @Condition nvarchar(max)
    if(@Date is null)
        BEGIN   
                Select  @Condition='WHERE 
                                 (( ISNULL(ProductID,0)=''' +@ProductID+') OR'+@ProductID+'''=0)AND
                                 (( ISNULL(BranchID,0)=''' +@BranchID+') OR '+@BranchID+'''=0)  '
                                 Declare @Query nvarchar(max);Select @Query=@mainSqlQuery+@Condition+@GroupBySect
                    EXEC sp_executesql @Query;
        END
     IF(@Date is not null)
        BEGIN   
                Select  @Condition='WHERE 
                                 CONVERT(DATETIME,FCSB.FCBuySellDate,105)=''' +@Date+''' AND
                                 (( ISNULL(ProductID,0)=''' +@ProductID+') OR'+@ProductID+'''=0)AND
                                 (( ISNULL(BranchID,0)=''' +@BranchID+') OR '+@BranchID+'''=0)  '
                     Declare @Query1 nvarchar(max);Select @Query=@mainSqlQuery+@Condition+@GroupBySection;
                    EXEC sp_executesql @Query1;
        END
```

*NOTE :-in this i need a condition to work in the where clause ,( Date is the main problem if date is null i need to display all details but in this when i put null in date no data will come, so i prefer this method but i know it is a worst method but the date condition need to display like this any other opinion to overcome the date in the where clause

Comment: @owcZark these are @productID(bigint) @ProductID(bigint), @BranchID(bigint) and @Date(DateTime),

Answer (score 0):

What type are `@ProductID`, `@BranchID` and `@Date`? I would try to convert those values to varchar explicitly when creating the condition.

Comment: @owcZark these are @productID(bigint) @ProductID(bigint), @BranchID(bigint) and @Date(DateTime),

Comment: So instead of using them  directly, convert them to varchar, like this: `(( ISNULL(ProductID,0)=''' +convert(varchar(255), @ProductID)+') OR'+convert(varchar(255), @ProductID)+'''=0)AND` Also, I'm not sure why you use the ''' - should the value be casted to varchar during the query execution? I belive, as the comparison is make to 0 in case of null value, there is no need to cast. Don't use the `'''`.

Comment: no, because.. i this i need a condition to work in the where clause ,( Date is the main problem if date is null i need to display all details but in this when i put null in date no data will come, so i preffer this method but i know it is a worst method but the date condition ineed to disply like this any other openion to overcome the date in the where clause

Comment: In the same line?